# does thread.sleep in quartz have to match the time for my schedule?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

This is a silly question but I can't seem to find the answer online.

If it is 9:00 am and I schedule a job at 12:00 pm do I need to set my `thread.sleep` to 3 hours?

In other words, if I set my `thread.sleep` to just 5 minutes and follow it with a `sched.shutdown(true)` will my job still run at noon? Or will the scheduler have already shut down? I don't get the point of `thread.sleep`...Can someone please clarify?

EDIT added code:

```
try {

          SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
          Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();

          JobDetail job = newJob(HelloWorld.class)
                            .withIdentity("job0","group1")
                            .build();

          CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
              .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
              .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 12 ? 1-12 2-6")) 
              .build();
          sched.scheduleJob(job,trigger);

          sched.start();

          Thread.sleep(300000L); //300000 milliseconds is 5 minutes
          sched.shutdown(true);

    } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IBTradeGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you are sleeping in your main method, or similar, so that your application does not terminate?  If your program does stop then the job will not run.

Comment: @darrenmc According to the documentation, you should sleep the thread after starting it so that the jobs have time to execute. I didn't understand if that meant sleep the thread until the job is scheduled, or just sleep it for a couple of minutes so that it can register in the scheduler before shutting down. I've added code to show you where my `thread.sleep` shows up. I'm using `Swing` and my try / catch block is within a method that occurs when a button is pushed. My `thread.sleep` is only within that buttons method if that helps...

Comment: I think the sleep is only in the example code to demonstrate quartz. It is not something I do in production code. I think it is best to start the scheduler when your application initializes and stop it when your application shuts down. Scheduling jobs is then handled in other parts of your program.

Comment: @darrenmc Ah that is a way smarter idea...Thank you. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sleep is only in the example code to demonstrate quartz. It is not something to do in production code.

It is best to start the scheduler when your application initializes and stop it when your application shuts down. Scheduling jobs is then handled in other parts of your program.